# Windows CMD, Using Find with Multiple Parameters

Tags: cmd

I am new to the Windows CMD and am running into an issue.  I am trying to figure out how to find items in the tasklist using multiple parameters.  In this case, I want to see items where the Image Name is Javaw.exe and the user is aaaa.  Taken seperately, each of these commands work:

```
tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq javaw.exe"
tasklist /V /FI "USERNAME eq ITSERVICES\aaaa"
```

What I need to know is how to combine them into 1 find request, where only items with both those criteria are shown?

Any help is appreciated.

Brandie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq javaw.exe" /FI "USERNAME eq ITSERVICES\aaaa"
```

note that a better place for this question (the correct place) is superuser.com as this is not a programming question.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I will accept your answer as soon as the alloted time period is up.

Comment: btw, note that typing tasklist /? would have answered this query

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell command to filter multiple processes
"Get-Process -Name chrome,atmgr,cmd"